# What does Hinich mean by "homotopy" and "contractible"?

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, model-categories

In ["Homological Algebra of Homotopy Algebras"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9702015.pdf), Hinich talks about homotopies and contractible (cochain) complexes. More specifically, I want to look at the following two points:

**§4.3, see also §6.5.** Let $(V,d)\in C(k)$ be an unbounded (cochain) complex over a ring $k$ and $\alpha:V\rightarrow V$ be a map of chain complexes of degree $0$. Hinich implies that the definition of a *homotopy* between $\text{id}_V$ and $\alpha$ is a map $h:V\rightarrow V$ of degree $-1$ such that
$$
dh = \text{id}_V-\alpha.
$$
This doesn't seem to match the usual definition of a chain homotopy: a map $h$ of degree $-1$ such that $dh+hd=\text{id}_V-\alpha$. Am I missing something or badly interpreting Hinich's statement?

**§4.4, see also §6.6.** Hinich introduces $(X,d_X)\in C(k)$, a *contractible* complex. While he does not clearly say what this means, I think* he means that there exists a "homotopy" $h$ between $\text{id}_X$ and $0$, that is, $d_Xh=\text{id}_X$. This is strange, as it would imply that the differential $d_X$ is surjective.

*The reason for this is that Hinich introduces another complex $A^\#$, defines the complex $(V,d)$ by $V=A^\#\oplus X$ and the map $\alpha:V\rightarrow V$ as $\alpha:A^\#\oplus X\rightarrow A^\#\rightarrow A^\#\oplus X$, and then says that there exists a homotopy $h$ that vanishes on $A^\#$ such that $dh=\text{id}_V-\alpha$ (it is actually written $dh=\alpha$, but I believe this is a mistake; compare with the definition of homotopy and with the similar statement in §6.6). Restricting the equation to $X$, we get $d_Xh=\text{id}_X$.

---

I'm not too confident in my interpretation of Hinich's statements, so I would be grateful if anyone could clarify these issues that I have :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your first question: d(h) = d∘h + h∘d (by definition), so Hinich's definition is the standard one.

For the second question, having d(h) = id defines a contractible chain complex,
since d(h) = d∘h + h∘d = id.

Comment: Thank you! That would explain the notation $d(h)$ instead of just $dh$ (even though later he writes $dH$ instead of $d(H)$...). I guess I am just not familiar enough with the notation.